# Java Change color of shape according to input

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I have this class where I create a star. When I run it I have message box which asks to choose a color. I want my star to be that color.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Control extends JPanel{
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
String background;
final Color color = Color.getHSBColor(0.56f, 1.0f, 0.8f);
final Color red=Color.red;
final Color green=Color.GREEN;
final Color yellow=Color.YELLOW;
private final double points[][] = { 
    { 0, 85 }, { 75, 75 }, { 100, 10 }, { 125, 75 }, 
    { 200, 85 }, { 150, 125 }, { 160, 190 }, { 100, 150 }, 
    { 40, 190 }, { 50, 125 }, { 0, 85 } 
};


private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                         RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                         RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    GeneralPath star = new GeneralPath();

    star.moveTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);

    for (int k = 1; k < points.length; k++)
        star.lineTo(points[k][0], points[k][1]);

    star.closePath();
    g2d.fill(star);  

    g2d.dispose();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA); //should be the color of chosen button
    super.paintComponent(g);
    doDrawing(g);
}


 public void addMessage() {
    Object[] options = {"Red","Green","Yellow", "Black"};
    int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, "Choose a color ", "Question of a day",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null,options, options[2]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if(options[i]=="Red"){
            //paint star red }
        else if(options[i]=="Green")
               //paint star ="Green"; 
        else if(options[i]=="Yellow")
            //paint star   ="Yellow"; 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's actually pretty easy: First, create a java.awt.Polygon with your points. Second, use Graphics2D.draw/fill(Shape)! For more, check out createStandardStar: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/util/ShapeUtils.java

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to have a `Color` object the user can set:

```
Color userChosenColor;

public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.userChosenColor = color;
}
```

Then set the color in `paintComponent` as such:

```
g.setColor(userChosenColor);
```

Alternatively (if you want them to be able to pick the widest range of colors), have them set the color based on red, green, and blue values:

```
public void setColor(int redVal, int greenVal, int blueVal) {
    this.userChosenColor = new Color(redVal, greenVal, blueVal);
}
```

**EDIT:**

After re-reading the question, you seem to be asking for how to set it to the same color as the color of a button. You can get the color of a button with `button.getBackground()`.

```
g.setColor(button.getBackground());
```